# Reasons you might choose to use a Θ(n log n) time algorithm over a Θ(n) time algorithm for the same task

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, big-o

This questions came up on a homework assignment. I cannot fathom why? It seems like you would always want to choose the algorithm that produces the best run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O and Big Theta notation only imply that for arbitrarily large input sizes, the performance tends towards some limit. For example, the function 99999999n is O(n) but the function (1/9999999999)n^2 is O(n^2). However, for any input of reasonable size (not infinitely large), the O(n^2) function is obviously likely to be faster.

In other words, if you can make assumptions about your input data, there are some cases where a generally worse algorithm may perform better.

A real world example of the above concept is sorting - there are some algorithms which perform in O(n) time if the array is already sorted (bubble sort). If you know a lot of your arrays already are sorted you may choose to use bubble sort over merge sort for this reason.

Another corner case where you might want to not use a more time-efficient algorithm is space efficiency. Maybe you are programming on an embedded device with very little RAM. You would rather use less memory and waste slightly more time than be as perfectly time-efficient as possible.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. Makes a lot of sense. Also, if you don't mind answering a follow up, my prof. said that big theta can be described as "the best case worst case time". Could you explain this in different words? My understanding is that big theta is a lower bound on the worst case input size. howevering im just paratting stuff i heard and am not sure what that even means.

Comment: @mdm508 Big O is the worst case time complexity, big Omega is the best case time complexity. Big Theta is a combination of both - if something is θ(n^2) it means that in both the worst case and the best case it will be limited above and below by the function k(n^2) where n is arbitrarily large and k is any constant. That, I assume, is why your professor called it the "worst case best case". If this helped you an upvote and accepted answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @mdm508 No worries - I hope my explanation helped in any case.